# iOS: On 'Automatic TabBar switched' method

Tags: ios

I'm trying to switch tabs programmatically and ensure that on switch the respective Navigation Controller pops to the root view controller. Is there a method that is invoked when tab bar is switched manually or programmatically?

Note: 
`-(void)tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` is only invoked on manual switching of the tab bars

Comment: how are you switching the tabBar programmatically?

Comment: ```[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:kSomeTab];```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try also calling didSelectViewController programmatically.  Check out babbidi's answer here:

[How to trigger method "tabBarController:didSelectViewController:" programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453530/how-to-trigger-method-tabbarcontrollerdidselectviewcontroller-programmatical)

Comment: Thanks. should've thought of this.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, the other way of doing this is using an observer on selectedViewController.

```
// Add Observer
// Note: tabBarController.selectedIndex is not observed as it does not call observeValueForKeyPath on manual switch
[self.tabBarController addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selectedViewController" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:@"changedTabbarIndex"];

// Method for Handling Observations
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    NSString *action = (__bridge NSString*)context;
    if([action isEqualToString:@"changedTabbarIndex"])
    {
        // Stuff to do on selected Tab changed
    }
}

// Change selectedViewController
[self.tabBarController setSelectedViewController:[[self.tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:kSomeTab]];
```

More Info:
[I didn't get any notifications when I touched on tabbar items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293054/i-didnt-get-any-notifications-when-i-touched-on-tabbar-items)